# how to fix null to be returned in flutter?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, null, android-developer-api, imagepicker

I have written this code for a complaint application. this is the screen where the user puts in the detailed info about the complaint. I have added an image picker to import images from the gallery or camera. but after I lot of research changing of code, this still shows this error. Someone please help as this is taking days.
My code;

```
class ComplaintNo1 extends StatefulWidget {



 @override
  _ComplaintNo1State createState() => _ComplaintNo1State();
}

class _ComplaintNo1State extends State<ComplaintNo1> {

  late File imageFile;

  _openGallery(BuildContext context) async{
    final picture = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    this.setState(() {
      imageFile= picture as io.File;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  _openCamera(BuildContext context) async{
    final picture = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    this.setState(() {
      imageFile= picture as io.File;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }


  Future<void> _showChoiceDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Make a choice!'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                child: Text('Gallery'),
                onTap: () {
                  _openGallery(context);
                },
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Text('Camera'),
                onTap: () {
                  _openCamera(context);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

   Widget _decideImageView() {
    if(imageFile == (null)) {
      return Text('No Image Selected!');
    }
    else {
      Image.file(imageFile,width: 100,height: 200);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.camera_alt,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
            _showChoiceDialog(context);
          }, child: Text('Select Image'),
          ),
           _decideImageView(),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Title of complaint',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.title),
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Time',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Starting date',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.date_range),
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Description of complaint',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.description),
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
            maxLines: 5,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the error
**The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.**

Answer (score 0):

Your `_decideImageView()` method is not returning the Image Widget

You've just to add the `return` keyword to your method :

```
Widget _decideImageView() {
  if(imageFile == (null)) {
    return Text('No Image Selected!');
  }
  else {
    return Image.file(imageFile,width: 100,height: 200);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but after adding the return this error is being shown. **LateInitializationError: Field 'imageFile' has not been initialized.**